# I changed boot/grub/menu.ls

Tags: linux, centos, grub

I commented out a wrong line in /boot/grub/menu.ls and now it tells me 
kernel panic - not syncing : VFS: unable to mount root fs on unknown - block (0,0) 
It stops there and does nothing. How can I change the file back and uncomment it.
I am unsing centos

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boot the PC/Server using a Linux Live CD, for example [KNOPPIX](http://www.knoppix.net/)  Once the desktop is loaded the partitions should be visible on the desktop.  Double click the partitions that contains /boot filesystem and edit menu.lst as required.  Maybe make a copy beforehand :)  If the partition is mounted as read only, right click the partition icon on the deskop and select Change Write/Read Mode.

Answer (score 2):

boot from a livecd like knoppix and edit the file again (by the way, it's /boot/grub/menu.lst , with a 't' at the end).

Answer (score 2):

boot from livecd(Ubuntu,SystemRescueCD,Knoppix) and mount /boot, and edit menu.ls

Answer (score 1):

Hit anykey during the boot up cycle. Then hit E to edit. Type in your grub password if you set one. Select the right line and uncomment. When it boots up edit the file and fix your mistake.